# Convert lib_string to <a href="string">string</a> w/o Regex

Tags: php

I need to convert `lib_someString`  to `<a href="someString">someString</a>` inside a block of text using str_replace [not regex].

Here's an example to give an exact sense what I mean: `lib_12345` => `<a href="12345">12345</a>`. I need to do this for a bunch of instances in a block of text.

Below is my attempt. Problem I'm getting is that my function is not doing anything (I just get lib_id returned).

```
function extractLibId($val){ // function to get the "12345" in the above example 
    $lclRetVal = substr($val, 5, strlen($val));
    return $lclRetVal;
}

function Lib($text){ // does the replace for all lib_ instances in the text
    $lclVar = "lib_";
    $text = str_replace($lclVar, "<a href='".extractLibId($lclVar)."'>".extractLibId($lclVar)."</a>", $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: Why no regex? Regexes are the right tool for this job!

Comment: why not regex? It would be a one-liner

Comment: Was hoping I can speed up my function w/o it. Pretty sure I don't need regex.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a simple regex is the option performing best here …

Comment: I'm usually against regular expressions as long as they are not useful, but this is a good scenario, where it is.

Comment: Regexes are only slow if you don't know when and how to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regexp gonna be faster and more clear, you will have no need to call your function for every possible 'lib_' string:

```
function Lib($text) {
    $count = null;
    return preg_replace('/lib_([0-9]+)/', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text, -1, $count);
}
$text = 'some text lib_123123 goes here lib_111';
$text = Lib($text);
```

Without regexp, but every time Lib2 will be called somewhere will die cute kitten:

```
function extractLibId($val) {
    $lclRetVal = substr($val, 4);
    return $lclRetVal;
}
function Lib2($text) {
    $count = null;
    while (($pos = strpos($text, 'lib_')) !== false) {
        $end = $pos;
        while (!in_array($text[$end], array(' ', ',', '.')) && $end < strlen($text)) 
            $end++;
        $sub = substr($text, $pos, $end - $pos);
        $text = str_replace($sub, '<a href="'.extractLibId($sub).'">'.extractLibId($sub).'</a>', $text);
    }
    return $text;
}

$text = 'some text lib_123123 goes here lib_111';
$text = Lib2($text);
```

Use preg_replace.

Comment: This of course assumes `someString` is a string of numbers only.

Comment: No need to specify `$limit` and `$count` parameters …

Comment: Sure, pattern has to be changed for certain purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is possible to do what you need without regular expressions, you say you don't want to use them because of performance reasons. I doubt the other solution will be faster, so here is a simple regex to benchmark against:

```
echo preg_replace("/lib_(\w+)/", '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $str);
```

As shown here: http://codepad.org/xGj78r9r

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring how ridiculous area of optimizing this is, even the simplest implementation with minimal validation already takes only 33% less time than a regex

```
<?php
function uselessFunction( $val ) {

    if( strpos( $val, "lib_" ) !== 0 ) {
    return $val;
    }

$str = substr( $val, 4 );

return "<a href=\"{$str}\">{$str}</a>";

}


$l = 100000;

$now = microtime(TRUE);

while( $l-- ) {
preg_replace( '/^lib_(.*)$/', "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>", 'lib_someString' );
}

echo (microtime(TRUE)-$now)."\n";
//0.191093

$l = 100000;
$now = microtime(TRUE);

while( $l-- ) {
uselessFunction( "lib_someString" );
}


echo (microtime(TRUE)-$now);
//0.127598
?>
```

Comment: Don't you think it will make a big difference if you have MBs worth of text?

Comment: It only gets much, much worse for the home brewed functions from here. The `uselessFunction` doesn't do what you want, it's just for demonstration. It replaces 1 "lib_ word" without any validation, while the regex is just waiting for a delimiter, character sets and removal of the match only from beginning and end signs.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your comment. Actually trying @Constantine's non-regex function on 2MB of text took only 10% to 15% the time.

Answer (score -1):

If you're restricted from using a regex, you're going to have difficult time searching for a string you describe as "someString", i.e. not precisely known in advance. If you know the string is exactly lib_12345, for example, then set $lclVar to that string. On the other hand, if you don't know the exact string in advance, you'll have to use a regex via preg_replace() or a similar function.

Comment: The string starts with `lib_` without a regex, you'd have to check if each word started with that.

Comment: This falls into the latter case - you don't know the exact string, only the first few characters. You'll want to use preg_replace or a similar function.